# cordova exclude non minified js from project

Tags: cordova, xcode5, minify

Do I need to manually remove the non minified js files from my project or is there a way to exclude or ignore them. Possible in xcode? I haven't found a good answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical solution for this would be to arrange your project into "src" and "build" directories. So, all of your original source code would go under "src" and your build process would produce a "build" which is intended to be executed, not modified. Hence, your minified code would go under "build" and the unminified code would go under "src".

This makes distributing the build much easier because it removes the bulky source code and utilities which are used for development (such as unit tests, deployment scripts, documentation, etc.) It also removes the need to compile on production which makes it faster and easier to deploy because it doesn't require time to be compiled and the compilation toolchain doesn't have to be installed (just the shared runtime libraries).

Additionally, you could also use the build directory to construct several different types of builds based on platform. For web development, it is traditionally accepted that there is only one build (because all browsers download the same source). This is not only not required, but in recent years, with the advent of platforms like Cordova, there is a need to have platform-specific builds.

Comment: Would I need to maintain the 2 directories or could I keep them in sync somehow excluding the non min js files?

Comment: You'd use a build script to "compile" the "src" code into a "build". Builds are expected to be completely recreated by the build script and not tracked by source control. You'd then only deploy builds to production, not the source.